# Как указать класс в качестве аннотации типа для полей этого же класса?

Tags: python, аннотации, типизация

Как сослаться на Класс внутри самого себя?

```
@dataclass
class Place:
    parent: Place
    children: list[Place]
```

```
parent: Place

NameError: name 'Place' is not defined.
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, в кавычки тогда нужно брать название класса, по-другому никак - он же ещё не определён действительно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используйте версию Python меньше 3.7, то нужно обернуть тип в кавычки:

```
@dataclass
class Place:
    parent: "Place"
    children: list["Place"]
```

Источник: [PEP-484 – Type Hints / Forward references](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references)

Начиная с Python 3.7 можно включить отложенное исполнение (postponed evaluation) аннотаций с помощью импорта `from __future__ import annotations`:

```
from __future__ import annotations


@dataclass
class Place:
    parent: Place
    children: list[Place]
```

Подробнее, см.:

- [PEP-484 – Type Hints / The problem of forward declarations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations)
- [PEP-563 - Postponed Evaluation of Annotations / Implementation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#implementation)

Планировалось, такое отложенное исполнение аннотаций будет включено по умолчанию в версии Python 3.10 (см. [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82786)), но изменения откатили из-за сломанной совместимости с такими библиотеками как Pydantic и FastAPI (см. [комментарий к issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82786#issuecomment-1093845440), [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/25490)), это изменение отложили как минимум до Python 3.11.