# Аннотация возвращаемого значения метода к типу его класса python

Tags: python, типы-данных, аннотации

**Python 3.8**

Есть класс с полем, тип данных которого этот же класс

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance = self
```

В одном из методов `MyClass` надо вернуть это поле, то есть тип данных этого же класса и сделать аннотацию

```py
def get_instance(self) -> MyClass: # Ошибка!
    return self.instance
```

Но аннотация подчёркивается с сообщением **Unresolved reference 'MyClass'**. При запуске интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку **NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined**

Как правильно написать аннотацию к методу, который возвращает тип класса, в котором находится этот метод? (В **Python 3.8**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы работал функционал автодополнения, т.е. PyCharm автоматически подтягивал имена методов исходя из возвращаемого типа, аннотации можно например определять так:

```
from typing import TypeVar

TMyClass = TypeVar("TMyClass", bound="MyClass")

class MyClass:
    def get(self) -> TMyClass:
        return

mc = MyClass()
mc.get().get()  # .get() автодополнение названия методов в PyCharm работает
```

можно и так

```
class MyClass:
    def get(self) -> 'MyClass':
        return

mc = MyClass()
mc.get().get()  # .get() автодополнение названия методов в PyCharm работает
```

Comment: Я не стал вдаваться в подробности, моей целью было убрать ошибку. Да я был уверен что анотация не будет работать, проверять не было времени.

Comment: Про свой второй варинат можете ещё что нибудь добавить, подробнее расказать?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references Когда подсказка типа содержит имена, которые еще не определены, это определение может быть выражено в виде строкового литерала, который будет разрешен позже.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1436357/208915 вот кстати еще один вариант с `__future__ `

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import Self


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance = self

    def get_instance(self) -> Self:
        return self.instance
```

Поздновато ответил, но может кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass = None

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def get(self) -> MyClass: # нужно сначала зарегистрироваться в пространстве имён, смотри выше 
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}"


mc = MyClass()
print(type(mc.get())) # <class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

Сама конструкция (-> MyClass) не обязывает питон вернуть вам именно этот тип данных, это просто подсказка для разработчиков.

Comment: это неправильно и к аннотации никакого отношения не имеет, в этом легко убедится, попытавшись получить имя MyClass-метода  из return mc.get() -> .get(), задействовав функционал автодополнения PyCharm